# How to stop HomePods from connecting every night?

Tags: airplay, homepod

We have two rooms in our house with HomePods. Every morning, they seem to be AirPlaying from one to the other, and we have to disconnect that AirPlay scenario.

Is there a way to avoid having the HomePods connect every night? We'd rather just treat them as separate speakers.

*To be clear, this isn't that they're forming a stereo-pair - it's that they are AirPlaying - like this:*

[image: our speakers air playing from one to the other]